# Simple Recursion Definition

Tags: recursion

I have the following equation which is what *f* is equals to, and am told to write the recursive definition for it.
I know that the base case is simply: when n = 0, we can say that the function *f* = 0^2+2(0)+1 = 1

However, for the recursive definition I am very stuck, as I do not know how to define it. I believe the mathematical formula for this is $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, yet I am unclear how to translate this.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2+2i+1$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850288

Comment: You already have the base case, now you just need to write a formula for $f(n)$ in terms of $f(n-1)$ and $n$. What happens when you stop the sum early?

Comment: "*I believe the mathematical formula for this is...*" $\;-\;$ That doesn't work even for $\,n=0\,$ or $\,n=1\,$. What you have there is $\,\sum_{i=1}^n\left(i+1\right)^2=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}i^2\,$.

Comment: There's no such thing as **the** recursive definition for $f$; there are infinitely many. Here's one: $f(n)=f(n-1)+n^2+2n+1$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect that the problem composer intends a response consistent with the comment of @GerryMyerson.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks greatly, I had arrived at this solution earlier but thought it was too simple to be correct. Everyones answers are appreciated.